# CarrierWave "default_url" with multiple images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have an `ImageUploader` class with a default_url method like this:

```
def default_url(*args)
   ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/default.png")
end
```

In my model, I have mounted multiple ImageUploaders

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   mount_uploaders :images, ImageUploader
end
```

These images are optional and the user may chose not to upload them. When that's the case, the model.images array is empty

```
model.images = []
model.images[0] = nil
```

Now, when I try to access an image in a view like this,

```
<img src=<%= model.images[0].url %> class="media-object" style="width:256px">
```

, it throws the nilClass error, which is perfectly understandable, given that model.images[0] is nil. **My question is how can I make it invoke a call to default_url in my view, if no images have been uploaded, in a multi-upload setting?**

Can this be done while creating/editing the record?

I don't prefer using `rescue` in view since I think the functionality for default_url is already there in CarrierWave and that should be used. Thanks.

PS: I am using Rails 4.2.4.

Answer (score -1):

```
<img src=<%= model.try(:images).first.url %> class="media-object" style="width:256px">
```

ruby > 2.3

```
<img src=<%= model.images&.first&.url %> class="media-object" style="width:256px">
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't solve my problem...and is not different from what I've mentioned in the question